# Did I do this integral word problem correctly? Water tank has $500000g$ and can be filled at a rate of...

Tags: calculus, integration

some function $F$. How many days will it take to fill the tank.

I solved this by taking the integral from $0$ to $x$ (plugged in values for $x$) using the function $F$ until the result was $500000g$. Was this the correct way? Something doesn't feel right.

Thank you,

Comment: The equation you want to solve is $500000=\int_0^T F(t)\,dt$.  More details about the function $F$, like is it in G/sec? G/day?, would help.

Comment: The function provides the rate of flow. something like (200e^x)/(1.2e^x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example of $200e^x$, and assuming gallons/day,
\begin{align*}
500000=\int_0^{T}200e^x\,dx=200e^x\big|_0^T=200e^T-200\\
\iff e^T=2501\iff T=\log2501=7.824.
\end{align*}
You can see how this would work with different specific numbers.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I guess I was on the right track.

Comment: Not a problem. Feel free to let me know if you need any more assistance.